# CakePHP 2 - Validating password fields

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have some problem with Cakephp 2 validation.

I am trying to validate several fields on an Edit form. Some of them are a password and confirm  password fields.

I want to validate both only if they are supplied. If they are empty I dont change the password, but if the user writes over them I would like to validate if they have a minLength or the passwords matchs.

Code:

```
'pwd' => array(
            'length' => array(
                'rule'      => array('between', 8, 40),
                'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
        ),
'pwd_repeat' => array(
            'length' => array(
                'rule'      => array('between', 8, 40),
                'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
            'compare'    => array(
                'rule'      => array('validate_passwords'),
                'message'   => 'The passwords you entered do not match.',
                'allowEmpty' => true
            ),
```

I dont know if I have to define some rules on edit() function in the controller or it should be enough, but my code is not working.

Thanks!

Edit: (Controller Code)

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->User->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Usuario incorrecto'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {

                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('El usuario ha sido actualizado.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('El usuario no ha podido actualizarse. Por favor, inténtelo de nuevo.'));      
                }
                unset($this->request->data['User']['pwd']);
                unset($this->request->data['User']['pwd_repeat']);
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('User.' . $this->User->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->User->find('first', $options);
    }
    $roles = $this->User->Role->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('roles'));
}
```

(View Code)

```
<div id="contenedor" class="users form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('name' => 'form')); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Editar Usuario'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('id');
    echo $this->Form->input('username', array('label' => __('Usuario')));
    echo $this->Form->input('pwd', array('label' => __('Contraseña'), 'type' => 'password', 'name' => 'pass', 'onKeyUp' => 'habilita()', 'value' => ''));
            echo $this->Form->input('pwd_repeat', array('label' => __('Repite Contraseña'), 'type' => 'password', 'name' => 'rpass', 'disabled' => 'disabled'));
    echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array('label' => __('Nombre')));
    echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array('label' => __('Apellidos')));
    echo $this->Form->input('telephone', array('label' => __('Teléfono')));
    echo $this->Form->input('email', array('label' => __('Email')));
    echo $this->Form->input('role_id', array('label' => __('Rol')));
?>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Aceptar')); ?>
```

Comment: what about `valdidate_passwords` function

Comment: Tip: Read [working-with-passwords-in-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/)

Comment: @mark I tried your solution previously, but it doesnt wor as I need. Your solution let me leave the password fields empty but not validating if they are supplied. I think I am doing something wrong

Comment: Definitely. Make sure you either define your own rules (fully), or leave them undefined alltogether. Mixing can cause troubles if you don't know how it behaves. Also make sure your whitelisting (if applied) is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the validation rules like this

```
'pwd' => array(
    'length' => array(
        'rule'      => array('between', 8, 40),
        'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
    ),
),
'pwd_repeat' => array(
    'length' => array(
        'rule'      => array('between', 8, 40),
        'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
    ),
    'compare'    => array(
        'rule'      => array('validate_passwords'),
        'message' => 'The passwords you entered do not match.',
    )
)
```

And your validate_passwords function should be like this.

```
public function validate_passwords() {
    return $this->data[$this->alias]['pwd'] === $this->data[$this->alias]['pwd_repeat']
}
```

Comment: I need let users leave the pwd and pwd_repeat fields empty, so the password doesnt change, but if user supplied anything, then I want validate these fields

Comment: you can make it by allowEmpty to true. can you tell me where you are struck.

Comment: With allowEmpty I solved the users could leave empty the password (unchanged password), but I am struggling about validating these fields if they are not empty (user wants to change his password). I don`t know why validation rules are not working in this case.

Comment: remove `'name' => 'pass'` & `'name' => 'rpass'` then try, it should work now

Comment: It works perfect! It should be some problem with the fieldnames. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anilkumar I appreciate your helping nature :)