# CakePHP 3 - Compare passwords

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have two field "password" (This field is in the database) and confirm_password (This field is not in the database)

Well, I need to compare if password == confirm_password.. but I'm not knowing create a custom validation to "confirm_password"... Would need to have this field in the database?

How do I do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Generally you can access all data in a [**custom validation rule**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#custom-validation-rules) via the `$context` argument, where it's stored in the `data` key, ie `$context['data']['confirm_password']`, which you could then compare to the current fields value.

```
$validator->add('password', 'passwordsEqual', [
    'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
        return
            isset($context['data']['confirm_password']) &&
            $context['data']['confirm_password'] === $value;
    }
]);
```

That being said, recently a `compareWith` validation rule was introduced which does exactly that.

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5813**

```
$validator->add('password', [
    'compare' => [
        'rule' => ['compareWith', 'confirm_password']
    ]
]);
```

Comment: How will I set a message? "Password Invalid"  using "compareWith"

Comment: Ok, just 'message' => 'Password Invalid".. But I would to know, How do I make to show this message bellow confirm_password field? 'cause it show bellow password field..

Comment: @ThiagoMoraes Simply add the same rule for the `confirm_password` field, and compare with `password`.

Comment: I'm confused, this method already existed in CakePHP 2. Why did it got added after the official release of CakePHP 3?

Comment: @Jordy I don't know what you are referring to, but `compareWith` is not available in CakePHP 2.x

Comment: @ndm I'm referring to the compare validation in CakePHP 2.x. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047117/cakephp-2-validating-password-fields

Comment: @Jordy That's something different, that's a custom validation rule similar to the first example in my answer, the `compareWith` rule on the other is a built-in rule in CakePHP 3.x, and there is no equivalent rule in CakePHP 2.x.

Answer (score 7):

Now there has a method call sameAs in validator class, for version 3.2 or grater.

```
 $validator -> sameAs('password_match','password','Passwords not equal.');
```

see [API](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/source-class-Cake.Validation.Validator.html#919-939)

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late answer but will help to other.

```
// Your password hash value (get from database )
$hash = '$2y$10$MC84b2abTpj3TgHbpcTh2OYW5sb2j7YHg.Rj/DWiUBKYRJ5./NaRi';
$plain_text = '123456'; // get from form and do not make hash. just use what user entred.
  
if (password_verify($plain_text, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

OR

```
$hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
$check = $hasher->check($plain_text,$hash); // it will return true/false
```