# How to confirm password in cakephp3

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I used this method but it didn't work , I have an error **Method confirmPassword does not exist**
 this is my code 
in add.ctp

```
 echo $this->Form->input('password');
 echo $this->Form->input('password2');
```

in usersTable

```
$validator
    ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
    ->notEmpty('password')
    ->add('password','minLength',[
        'rule'=>['minLength',6],
        'message'=>'Vous devez entrer un mot de passe plus que 6 caractéres'
    ])
    ->requirePresence('password2')
    ->add('password2','custom',[
        'rule'=>'confirmPassword',
        'message'=>'votre confirmation n est pas valide']);
```

And I implemented in usersTable the function `confirmPassword()`

```
 public function confirmPassword() {
        if ((isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']) && isset($password['password2']))
            && !empty($password['password2'])
            && ($this->data[$this->alias]['password'] === $password['password2'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I think you want to verify if the same user has entered the same password twice. You should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28401970/1604068

Comment: thank you very much !!!! it works with the rule" comparewith "

Answer (score 0):

You can call function `confirmPassword()` in the users controller and then proceed if true.
Add below in the controlller.

```
$this->Users->confirmPassword()
```